# OAuth token parameter missing when using request_youtube API

Tags: codeigniter, youtube-api

I try to using youtube API in code ingniter and using librari from https://github.com/jimdoescode/CodeIgniter-YouTube-API-Library when i call `request_youtube()`from direct link the https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth1/auth sent massage like this :

**400. That’s an error.
OAuth token parameter missing.
That’s all we know.**

This the code of request_youtube() :

```
public function request_youtube()
 {
 $params['key'] = xxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
 $params['secret'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
 $params['algorithm'] = 'HMAC-SHA1';
$this->load->library('google_oauth', $params);
 $data = $this->google_oauth->get_request_token(base_url().'index.php/example/access_youtube');
 $this->session->set_userdata('token_secret', $data['token_secret']);
 redirect($data['redirect']);
 }
```

what wrong with my code...or any step i miss???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library that you are using is deprecated probably because of which it is unable to make calls to the Google Servers and is returning 404 errors. You can still follow the original way of authentication using OAuth where you validate your app with the client id client secret and get the Auth code. With the Auth code making a POST request and getting a access token and a refresh token in exchange. For details please refer to this official Google [Youtube Documentation on OAuth](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2).